# Prevent text from selecting in react-naitve

Tags: react-native

Code looks like this:

```
<Pressable>
  <Text>Click me</Text>
</Pressable>
```

When pressable is clicked, background color of text is changing, how to prevent it in react-native from changing?

Comment: Background color doesn't change by default when pressable is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Background color doesn't change by default when pressable is clicked. But if you are facing this issue just give background color to Pressable none

```
<Pressable style={{backgroundColor: "none" }}>
  <Text>Click me</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: Pressble does not change color by default.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<Pressable style={({pressed})=>[styles.text, {backgroundColor: pressed ? 'white' : 'white' }]}>
   <Text> Click Me! </Text>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: Pressble does not change color by default.

Answer (score -1):

Actually this one do the trick `suppressHighlighting` applied to the `Text` component

Comment: Pressble does not change color by default.